# Mule Choice Expression - Routing based off Outbound property

Tags: syntax, expression, eval, esb, mule

I have a property I am extracting from the Message's Payload and setting into an Outbound property (to make it easier to access).  I want to simply check the size of this property, but all my best guesses are giving me exceptions.

I've tried using the #[header:OUTBOUND:count] syntax, adding an evaluator="header" attribute to the <when> tag, nothing seems to be working.  I've tried other evaluators as well, but I cannot find any Mule documentation with examples of syntax, so I'm just guessing how the expressions should be formed.

```
<choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="message.outboundProperties['count']==0">
            <processor-chain>
                ... something here ...
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <processor-chain>
                ... alternate option ...
            </processor-chain>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're running Mule 3.3.0 and that `count` is numeric, your syntax is correct and should work as is.

To make it canonical, add `#[]` around the expression:

```
<when expression="#[message.outboundProperties['count'] == 0]">
```

Because its name is compatible with MVEL attribute naming, you could even access the `count` entry directly:

```
<when expression="#[message.outboundProperties.count == 0]">
```

Comment: Yes, I was using 3.2 by mistake.  That's what I get for having 3 versions of Studio installed...

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of scenario I ussually use Groovy. 
Try this

```
<when expression="message.getProperty('count',org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope.OUTBOUND)==0"
evaluator="groovy"/>
```

HTH